# React - Periodically fetch Data (Webrequests)

Tags: reactjs, axios, httpwebrequest

I've got a ReactJS Project and want to fetch data periodically by using axios.

For instance I would like to send GET Requests like:

- Request A every two minutes
- Request B & C every three minutes
- Request D every five minutes
- Request E,F every six minutes
- Request G every six and a half minutes

I tried using the following in componentDidMount():

```
setInterval(() => { }, 60 * 1000 * 2);
setInterval(() => { }, 60 * 1000 * 3);
...
```

Which seems to be a really bad idea, because some of my components always perform a rerender (for instance my slider carousel does not slide any more).

What is the best solution to do such periodically fetches?

Answer (score 0):

The above use case has 2 variating parameters:

1. Time Interval(s) - 2, 3, 5, 6, 6.5
2. Web Request(s) :- A, B, C, D, E, F, G

Create an array of objects as [{webRequest1 : timeInterval1}, .. {webRequestN : timeIntervalN}]. That defines the required mappings, can be done in some config file where all the configurations are available.

Create a function which would take this array as parameter and make an axios call. Create timers like start timer and end timer which has to be maintained individually for each mapping.

Hope this gives some insight to solve the issue.